# Extra scrollbar on new google site when using embed code

Tags: html, css, google-sites-2016

I was trying to embed my code on my new google site but it looks like there is an extra scrollbar on the embed code section. At first I thought it was the size too short but after I have adjusted the size is still the same, I still can see the scrollbar from the embedded code section.

Does anyone know how to prevent this?

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to look into problem if you share you link or jsfiddle link.

Comment: @AryanTwanju It's a Google site, the website is not ready yet so I cannot publish it. The code is just normal html and css code.

Comment: The <div> or some other html element where the extra scrollbar is appearing, it might have been assigned overflow: auto or overflow: scroll property. If its there, remove it.

Comment: @AryanTwanju Btw, there is no such property in my code.

Comment: @Ace did you inserted as iframe, if yes then there must be height defined in that iframe code

Comment: Having this same issue, any solution?

Answer (score 11):

To disable scrolling for embed code, add :

```
<script>
parent.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].scrolling="no";
</script>
```

This changes the scrolling value of the parent iFrame ( scrolling="yes" ) to no.)

You can change the no to auto in the code if you want it to add scrolling automatically.

Answer (score 0):

As @Vico said, you can remove the scrolling with the added  but that will most likely just remove scrolling and not make your embed URL Responsive.

Unfortunately there **is not a way** to actually communicate your mobile environment from your google site to your embedded URL because the new google sites embed uses iFrame. The only work around would be to increase the size of your embedded container on your google site **drastically**. Once you do that you should be able to view your full webApp or what not on your site with no up-down scrolling but you may still see side-to-side scrolling. To remove that you van add

`<body style="overflow: hidden;">`

and it will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this trick will help: Expand the inserted "Embed < >" box's boundary. (from
[Auto adjust heigth of Google Site embed code (html)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66521908/auto-adjust-heigth-of-google-site-embed-code-html))